# netlify: WebSocket connection failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server, gulp

I have app on Netlify and I get some error: 
server don't work: 9aeacd2….js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/:5000' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response. Only start site is served.
Locally all works perfect and I wasn't getting any error. App builds on Netlify (gulp) and this is angular app.
Help me and thanks!

My server code:

```
"use strict";

process.title = 'node-chat';

var webSocketsServerPort = (process.env.PORT || 5000);

var webSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');
var pref = '../';
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('src/index.html');
var clients = [];
var loggedUsers = [];
var tables = [];
var err;
/**
* HTTP server
*/
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var status;
    var type;
    var file = null;
    switch (req.url) {
    case "/":
    case "/src/index.html":
        file = index;
        status = 200;
        type = "text/html";
        break;

    default:
        status = 404;
        type = "text/plain";
}
res.writeHead(status, {'Content-Type': type});
if (file !== null) {
    res.end(file);
} else {
    res.end();
}
});

server.listen(webSocketsServerPort, function () {
    console.log((new Date()) + " Server is listening on port " + 
webSocketsServerPort);
});

/**
 * WebSocket server
 */
var wsServer = new webSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

wsServer.on('request', function (request) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + 
'.'    );

var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

var index = clients.push(connection) - 1;

connection.on('message', function (message) {
    if (message.type === 'utf8') { // accept only text
      var json = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);
      switch(json.type){
        case 1:
          break;


      }

    }
});

// user disconnected
connection.on('close', function (connection) {
    console.log("DISCONNECTED");
});
});
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this @yoyo33 I'm experiencing the same thing. Works fine on DigitalOcean and locally but throws an error on netlify.